# Logical flow to check for receipt of a bitcoin payment

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, payment, receiving

I'm experimenting with writing some Bitcoin software in Node.JS using the [node-bitcoin](https://github.com/freewil/node-bitcoin) lib to talk directly to my own `bitcoind` via `JSON-RPC`, and I am trying to work out the best-practice way to recognise when a bitcoin payment has been received by an address.

The only way I can really think of doing is is as follows:

1. a recipient provides the Bitcoin address they wish to receive payment to (presumes they have their own wallet already - else I could generate one for them)
2. My webpage generates a QR code in the proscribed format for a user's smartphone wallet app to scan.
3. The user scans the QR code and sends payment via their wallet app
4. I then assumed I could poll `getreceivedbyaddress` with the recipient's address until the transactions showed up, but [the docs](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) explicitly state that this:

> Works only for addresses in the local wallet, external addresses will always show 0.

So I assume the solution is to generate a new receiving address for the recipient rather than let them provide their own receiving address. Ideally in this situation I'd generate a new receiving address for each sale the recipient makes.

Then I can easily poll `getreceivedbyaddress`, analyse the raw transaction when I see it come in, and, assuming it all makes sense, ping a web-socket event to the webpage telling it to close the QR code and spit out a formal receipt.

Does that make sense or is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: related: [How to know when a payment has been received by bitcoind?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/7132/5406)

Comment: Cool thanks!  I'll go read up on `-WalletNotify`

Comment: You're welcome. If the linked question answers your question completely, please kindly flag your own question as a duplicate.

Comment: Good idea.  I've done that now.