# The setup steps for generating bitcoin addresses programmatically and checking for payments with walletnotify

Tags: bitcoind, hosting, wallet-notify

I have read this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29969/logical-flow-to-check-for-receipt-of-a-bitcoin-payment) and done some investigation, and I want to make sure I have some of this right.

If I have a server somewhere where I can install bit coin (I'm thinking bitcoin-qt on Ubuntu) then I can run *bitcoind* on that computer.

I could setup a http server to accept requests for a new bitcoin address from bitcoind and return one to my other web app (hosted on Google App Engine).

Then as I understand it, if I setup walletnotify, it will automatically call my scripts to process payments that are received.

I'm thinking I might be able to get away with putting this in a friend's living room, though I'm not entirely sure I will have a static IP address, but maybe I can work that out.

I realize there are 3rd party solutions for this, and this is a broad question with many ins and outs, and I should be more knowledgeable of Bitcoin and hosting my own servers (as the PaaS solutions don't seem to let you run *bitcoind*), but do I have that mostly right or is there is something amiss with this endeavor.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a solid approach.